# Canvas CORS security error in Safari only

Tags: javascript, safari, cors

How can i set dataURL format('"data:image/svg+xml;base64,"' ) svg to img.src in safari?(It's OK in chrome.).

Safari will throw securityError.
Any method to make the dataURL's domain right?

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = myLoader;
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';       
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,...............";
var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because you've got a `<foreignObject>` element in your SVG document.

For Security reasons, Safari v.9+ will taint the canvas when this element is drawn on it.

No workaround except removing it from your SVG ;-)

Ps: IE prior to Edge will also taint the canvas, once any svg has been drawn to it.

Comment: yes,there's a <foreignObject> element in svg.I just want to convert a dom to svg then to a png file.

Comment: Well you can't do it this way, not in Safari, nor in IE prior to Edge and only with horrible limitations in other browsers anyway. That's a hack, and if you were reading the MDN article about it, that should be removed from there. To achieve what you want, use a library that will actually draw your elements, such as [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/)